# .htaaccess won't work on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello so am trying to make some .htaccess rules but nothing of what I write works!

I am using XAMPP for windows 8.1.

The `.htaccess` I wrote is to remove the `.php` extension:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I want the link to be `localhost/sadeqrasheed/demo/home` instead of `localhost/sadeqrasheed/demo/home.php`.

The `.htaccess` file is in the same place as the `home.php` in the demo folder.

But it's not working. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `AllowOverride All` in your vhost configuration. Otherwise your htaccess is not working.